# How to update an existing object with Diesel? "`T: Identifiable` is not satisfied"

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I have this struct:

```
#[derive(Identifiable, Queryable, Debug)]
#[table_name = "users"]
pub struct QueryableUser {
    pub id: i32,
    pub username: String,
    pub password: String,
    pub sex: bool,
    pub profile: Option<String>,
    pub birth: chrono::NaiveDate,
}
```

When I try to update the struct like so:

```
diesel::update(&queryable_user).set(...);
```

it gives me this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `user::QueryableUser: diesel::Identifiable` is not satisfied
  --> src\message_handler\set_profile.rs:36:13
   |
36 |             diesel::update(user).set(profile.eq(None));
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Identifiable` is not implemented for `user::QueryableUser`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <&'ident user::QueryableUser as diesel::Identifiable>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_builder::IntoUpdateTarget` for `user::QueryableUser`
   = note: required by `diesel::update`
```

It's really confusing because I used `#[derive(Identifiable)]` on my struct.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation on [`Identifiable`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.8/diesel/associations/trait.Identifiable.html):

> This must be implemented to use associations. Additionally, implementing this trait allows you to pass your struct to update (`update(&your_struct)` is equivalent to `update(YourStruct::table().find(&your_struct.primary_key())`).
>
> This trait is usually implemented on a reference to a struct, not the struct itself.

So you simply need to borrow `user`:

```
diesel::update(&user).set(...);
```